# Python Mockito: How do I set up async mocks?

Tags: python, mockito, python-asyncio

The following code works as expected for the synchronous part but gives me a TypeError for the async call (TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression), presumably because the mock constructor can't properly deal with the spec. How do I properly tell Mockito that it needs to set up an asynchronous mock for `async_method` ?

```
class MockedClass():
    def sync_method(self):
        pass

    async def async_method(self):
        pass

class TestedClass():
    def do_something_sync(self, mocked: MockedClass):
        mocked.sync_method()

    async def do_something_async(self, mocked: MockedClass):
        await mocked.async_method()

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test():
    my_mock = mock(spec=MockedClass)
    tested_class = TestedClass()

    tested_class.do_something_sync(my_mock)
    verify(my_mock).sync_method()

    await tested_class.do_something_async(my_mock) # <- Fails here
    verify(my_mock).async_method()
```

Edit:
For reference, this is how it works with the standard mocks (the behavior that I expect):
[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the real code you're actually used to get the error message.  I would expect this to fail at ``tested_class.do_something_sync(my_mock)``.  Generally, you don't configure the mock, for example using `when`, and so every method returns `None`as per default.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say but this code works as is (and throws where indicated with the comment). Since nobody could answer this question I went back to the standard unit test library which correctly gives you an AysncMockMixin if you provide a spec with async method definitions.

Comment: Oh my fault, sorry.  Looks like `mock(spec=SomeClass)` is not the same as `mock(SomeClass)` in mockito. I probably do a PR here because that's so confusing it must be a bug.  FWIW I assumed `mock(someClass)` behavior and this would have thrown differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mockito `my_mock.async_method()` would not return anything useful by default and without further configuration.  (T.i. it returns `None` which is not awaitable.)

What I did in the past:

```
# a helper function
def future(value=None):
    f = asyncio.Future()
    f.set_result(value)
    return f

# your code
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test():
    my_mock = mock(spec=MockedClass)
    when(my_mock).async_method().thenReturn(future(None))  #  fill in whatever you expect the method to return
    # ....
```

Comment: That works well when mocking methods taking no arguments. When the stub has arguments, this has a tendency to return None, fail and it is near impossible to figure out what arguments mismatch. Sometimes you will end up having to completely bypass Mockito and just write a manual mock just to figure out why the arguments don't match.

Comment: @EricBuist Maybe you can publish an example somewhere.  It sounds like you're using "dumb" non-strict mocks.  Those answer `None` to all questions by default.  But when you're create a mock after a `spec`, or just do `when(theRealClass)...`, you're in strict mode by default and mockito should scream loud if a method is unexpectedly used.